# Side Tabs Text Vertical Alignment - Text Orientation - What is better to read upside down or read bottom up?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, navigation, tabs, ease-of-use

I have a page with tabs on the side vertically aligned, with two options.

[image: Different Orientations]

**Questions**:

1. What was your gut reaction to the text orientation changes?
2. What is the best practice for text orientation. (see the examples above)
3. For the best practice what reasoning did you use?

The reasoning I am considering:

Starting place my users read right to left, top to bottom, and of course the text is not upside down.

Option **A**: If the text top points to the right then from the position of a readers eyes in relation to the screen they are to the right of the text. So in a way you're reading above the text seeming to be upside down, then you also read down the page.

**A** - Essentially, reading the text upside down, but from the top of the page to the bottom.

Option **B**: If I am looking to the tabs on the left of my screen with the text top to the left then when I read my eye view position is at an angel that is below the text, But then I read up the screen from the bottom to the top.

**B** - Essentially, reading the text right side up, but from the bottom of the of the page to the top.

Full Page example view
[image: Left aligned]

Comment: This is not a place for user testing, please try to limit your questions to a single problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the placement of the text. You need to consider how the user will tilt their head to read the text.

So if the text is on the left of the screen, Option B would be the way to go while option A if the text was on the right of the screen.

[image]